# How do I run eclipse remotely using Cygwin?

Tags: eclipse, cygwin

I'm running on Windows 7 and I want to be able to access the remote linux server at my school to run eclipse and do my programming assignments.

I installed cygwin, and ssh into the server, but whenever I run the "eclipse" command, it says "Eclipse: Cannot open display".

Is there any additional software I need to do, or commands I need to run in order to display the gui from my windows 7 computer?

aside from just running eclipse on my own computer, I want to do it remotely.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Run an X server on your Windows machine; there's an xorg-server package in cygwin, use that (or the independent Xming).
2. Configure your ssh client to forward X11 traffic to the X server on your windows machine.

[Here's a more detailed tutorial](http://www.math.umn.edu/systems_guide/putty_xwin32.html) on doing this.