# how to launch eclipse on linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, macos

I have eclipse installed on a linux server.

I am trying to launch this eclipse from my mac machine via terminal.

But I get the following error;

```
./eclipse
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Eclipse: Cannot open display: 
Eclipse: Cannot open display: 
Eclipse:
An error has occurred. See the log file
```

I wanted to know how to launch eclipse?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Work on a remote project with Eclipse via SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4216822/608639), [Run Eclipse project on a remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5734309/608639) and [How do I run eclipse remotely using Cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19651615/608639)